# Changing Member Password in MySQL through PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, passwords

I've tried and tried creating a form to change your password, but I can't seem to get it right, please help! It is now telling me that "Query failed" each time I try to change the password, there are other variables such as username, first name that are involved however the user is only allowed to change their password so I had only included `UPDATE members SET 'passwd'` -- These are the variables created when someone initially registers, `members(firstname, username, login, passwd, ip) VALUES('$fname','$uname','$login','".md5($_POST['password'])."','$ip')";`

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');
require_once('auth.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$retpassword = clean($_POST['retpassword']);

//Input Validations
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($retpassword == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Please retype your password';
    $errflag = true;
}
if( strcmp($password, $retpassword) != 0 ) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'New passwords do not match!';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the settings page
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: settings.php");
    exit();
}

//Create UPDATE query
$qry = "UPDATE members SET 'passwd' = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' WHERE login = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: changed.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: Well done for hashing your passwords (albeit MD5 is not a strong hashing function for passwords), but one really should *salt* those hashes.

Comment: are you sure you getting POST variables back?

Comment: @eggyal Haha thanks, yeah, I'm not sure how to SALT hashes, and security is not my greatest concern, I'll probably salt later on :P

Comment: @BojanKovacevic That was my mistake I forgot to method post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has to do more with the form you use to send the data.

Check the form `method="POST"` and check the names on your input fields.

Your form should look like this to be working with your PHP code

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="password" name="retpassword">
</form>
```

Comment: yes that was my mistake, thanks for that, however now I seem to get a query failed each time I try to change the password.

Comment: That probably has to something with '{$_SESSION['username']}' what should be '".$_SESSION['username']."'

Comment: I did correct that, however I still seem to get a query failure

Comment: I suggest you get the sql query and the database error and start a new question.